# return multiple row with same clones name mysql-php

Tags: php, mysql, row

I want to get all users from NY city by this codes:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from tbl_city WHERE city='ny'");   
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))    {
 $a="$row->username";}
 echo $a;
```

But it just returns the first one. How can I get more rows?

Comment: You keep on changing the `$a` variable, but you only output it after the last loop. It's like change a to 1. Change it to 2. To 3. Output a. A = 3

Comment: Also please stop using `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated for over 3 years now and they will no longer work in PHP 7+. Considder using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead in combination with [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written **echo $a** outside the loop, please modify your code with this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from tbl_city WHERE city='ny'");   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))    
{
    $a=$row->username;
    echo $a; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the username, then there is no need to use extra variable. You can do as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from tbl_city WHERE city='ny'");   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))    
{
    echo $row->username;
}
```

Although,`mysql_query()` is deprecated. Hence, I'll suggest you to use `mysqli->query()` instead as follows:

```
$result = mysqli->query("select * from tbl_city WHERE city='ny'");   
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())    
    {
        printf ("%s\n", $row->userame);
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: in which query?

Comment: i've removed the extra space between username and semi-colon(;). Kindly check it out.

Comment: If the above answer is working as expected, kindly upvote it whenever you'll get enough reputation (15). That'll be really helpful for future visitors.